# The type org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD cannot be resolved

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I am getting this error when i try the below code in Eclipse.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("simple hive app").setMaster("local");
JavaSparkContext javaSparkCtx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
HiveContext hiveContext = new HiveContext(javaSparkCtx.sc());
//hiveContext.sql("show tables").collect();
```

I am using below dependencies.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

It seems SchemaRDD class has been removed from version 1.3. I am not sure what is the problem in my code. Can any one help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your old version of spark-hive (1.2.1), which still requiers SchemaRDD. Bump it up to 1.4.0.

Comment: how to connect to specific database in hive and get all the tables?

Comment: you can do this from your system shell and use a "show tables" command